# Read an array from a php file

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP file,But data of the file is the **Array**.

When i open the file , i am able to get its content, but am unable to read it as an array. Its just reading as a string. Is there any way to read a php file as array.

My php file looks like,

```
<?php $someArray = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'data' => 'sadsa',
    'sadsad' => 'sdsss',
    ...... 
    'DOB' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'Day' => '12',
        'Month' => '12',
        'Year' => '12',
      ),
    ),
    ..
    ...
  ),
  1 => 
  ...........
  ...
  2 =>
  ...
  ....
```

Reading the file using,

```
file_get_contents ( '$filepath' );
```

Now i want to read the file and access it as an array.

Comment: You would need to `include` or `require` or what have you.

Comment: use `include` instead

Comment: [php.net/include](http://php.net/include)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You don't need `file_get_contents()` for the goal you intend to achieve ***since the file contains a declared Variable***. What you need is **include the file in your Current Script and access the Array as if it was declared in the same script** as shown below. Remember that `file_get_contents()` will always return the contents of a File *as a String*. Ideally (in this case), this is not what you need.

```
<?php
    // CURRENT SCRIPT: --- PSUEDO FILE-NAME: test.php
    require_once $filepath;    //<== $filepath BEING THE PATH TO THE FILE CONTAINING 
                               //<== YOUR DECLARED ARRAY: $someArray

    // JUST AS A DOUBLE-CHECK, VERIFY THAT THE VARIABLE $someArray EXISTS
    // BEFORE USING IT.... HOWEVER, SINCE YOU ARE SURE IT DOES EXIST, 
    // YOU MAY WELL SKIP THIS PART AND SIMPLY START USING THE $someArray VARIABLE. 
    if(isset($someArray)){
        var_dump($someArray); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are able to load the whole file as an array with the include function, you are also able to load the file with require or include.

**Array file**

```
<?php return array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'data' => 'sadsa',
    'sadsad' => 'sdsss',
    ...... 
    'DOB' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'Day' => '12',
        'Month' => '12',
        'Year' => '12',
      ),
    ),
    ..
    ...
  ),
  1 => 
  ...........
  ...
  2 =>
  ...
  ....
```

**Load file**

```
<?php
$someArray = include $filepath;
```

You are able to include your array file too, with the `include` function and use the $someArray variable.